# Passing Primary Key Id as parameter to JS function in custom CGridColumn "Click" array parameter

Tags: gridview, yii

I have a CButtonColumn in my CGridView pressing which invokes my JS routine. The JS routine makes the Ajax call and deletes a record. I need to pass the primary key of my record to the JS function to delete the intended record. I have consulted [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/) link and was able to attach the JS with my customized button call and tested it by hardcoding a PK value. One approach which is mentioned in the same link is to access the text in the first column of the grid was useful (please refer to myBtn column code given below where jQuery code is used). Using that approach if I display the PK column in the gird then my problem is solved but showing the PK values to users is definitely not a choice. I even tried to hide the column by setting the htmlOPtions using display:none but that leaves me with the column heading still dangling on top which looks very shabby.

Following is my JS (Please excuse me for bad formatting, I tried a lot but could not fit it in the code snippet tags, something stackoverflow to work on :)

```
function DeleteRec(Rec_id) {
    alert(Rec_id); 
    //var Rec_id=27;
    var data=$("#subject-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({   
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("upm/subject/deleteRec/id"); ?>'+'/'+Rec_id,   
        data:data,
        success:function(data){
            var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
            alert(myObject.recDelete);      
        },
        error: function(data) { // if error occured
            var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
            alert("Error occured.please try again"+myObject);
            var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
            var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject);
        },
        dataType:'html'
    });
}
```

Following is the my CGridView Code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $PatHistoryGrid,
    'id' => 'PatGrid',
    'enableSorting' => false,
    'enablePagination' => false,
    'columns' => array(
        'id' => array(
            'name' => '', 
            'value' => '$data->id', 
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'display:none;',)
        ),
        'Pat' => array(
            'name' => 'Pat Name', 
            'value' => '$data->pat->pat_val', 
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '240'),
        ),
        'PatDate' => array(
            'name' => 'Date', 
            'value' => '$data->pat_date', 
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '80', 'align' => 'middle')
        ),
        'PatNotes' => array(
            'name' => 'Pat Notes', 
            'value' => '$data->pat_notes', 
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '480', 'align' => 'middle')
        ),
        'PatPreNotes' => array(
            'name' => 'Pat Pre Notes', 
            'value' => '$data->pat_pre_notes', 
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '480', 'align' => 'middle')
        ),
        'Flag' => array(
            'type' => 'raw', 
            'name' => 'Flag', 
            'value' => '$data->flag', 
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '50')
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{update} {delete} {myBtn}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'myBtn' => array(
                    'click' => 'function(){
                        DeleteRec($(this).parent().parent().children(":first-child").text());
                    }',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'style' => 'margin-top:-40px;'
    ),
));
```

Is there a way to add a CGridColumn and yet not to be displayed, like a hidden variable in form? If that's possible then I will be able to solve this problem. Any other ideas are most welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot mashingan for formatting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class for your button:

```
'buttons' => array(
    'myBtn' => array(
        'options' => array('class' => 'myBtn')
    ),
),
```

And then in your JS you can get an id following Yii way:

```
$('#PatGrid').on('click', '.myBtn', function() {
    var id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getKey(
        'PatGrid',
        $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length 
    );
    alert(id);
    /* Your code */
});
```

Comment: but from where will I get the PK of the record to delete...? That was something I was not able to get. Please review my own answer in in which I added a new RAW column in my grid with its contents taken from model property. The problem is resolved, thanks for your feedback and reply. Regards, Faisal

Comment: `$.fn.yiiGridView.getKey` will return you a PK of your model. Try it if you don't beleave ;)

Comment: I tried your solution but this returns me the contents of the first TD in TR, which in my case is not the PK of the row, since I am not showing it. If I include the PK column in the grid then I do get the ID. Let me highlight here that I was primarily focusing on getting the ID when I didn't have it in the DOM. That was the core reason for which I had to go back in model. Anyway, in my earlier efforts, I managed to get the same results using one approach with no results but the one you suggested is also not bad at all. I will keep note it of for many other solutions. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Ah, damn it. I forgot to remove click handler in CGridView. It will work even if you don't display PK in grid at all, because Yii saves your model's PK in hidden div. Anyway, your solution should work as well. Have a good day )

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and I dumped my solution. This is much more elegant and neat...so many thanks mashingan...!

Answer (score 1):

I devised the solution. I created new a property in my model which returned the anchor HTML with the JS function name and the PK as its parameter. I added a new column in the grid and made its value to that property. The only difference in this column and other regular columns is that it contains its type as raw. Following is the code snippet of my model property:

```
    public function getDataDel(){
     return '<a class="myBtn" title="myBtn" click="DeleteRec('.$this->id.') " href="#">myBtn</a>';
}
```

Following is my new CGridView code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$PatHistoryGrid,
'id'=>'PatGrid',
'enableSorting'=>false,
'enablePagination'=>false,
'columns'=>array('Pat'=>array('name'=>'Pat Name','value'=>'$data->pat->pat_val', 'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'240'),),
                  'PatDate'=>array('name'=>'Date','value'=>'$data->pat_date','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'80','align'=>'middle')),    
                  'PatNotes'=>array('name'=>'Pat Notes','value'=>'$data->pat_notes','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'480','align'=>'middle')),                  
                  'PatPreNotes'=>array('name'=>'Pat Pre Notes','value'=>'$data->pat_pre_notes','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'480','align'=>'middle')),
                  'Flag'=>array('type'=>'raw','name'=>'Flag','value'=>'$data->flag','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'50')),
    'Delid'=>array('type'=>'raw','name'=>'Btns','value'=>'$data->dataDel','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'50')),
),
'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'margin-top:-40px;'),));
```

Comment: what's the relation between getDataDel() function on the model with the gridview?

Comment: ah ic, datayDel --> typo i guess

Comment: this is a function that returns the HTML for the button I needed to delete  the row. I am calling another JS function "DeleteRec" passing the Pk Id. If you notice the type of column where I have used get DataDel is "Raw". Since this is a getter, so the "get" word is omitted when this is referenced in the grid. Hope it helps...